# Rule for using suppressor and suppressant

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is it okay to say "caffeine is an appetite suppressor"? A colleague of mine told me it should be "caffeine is an appetite suppressant". However, I don't know a rule on when to use either of them.

Comment: The only contexts where I commonly hear "suppressor" are in genetics, where you can have "suppressor cells" and "suppressor genes", and in firearms, where it's a synonym for "silencer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, *suppressor* refers to a **person or machine** which suppresses something else. Here's one example:

> The president reduced murders by 50% and theft by over 90%. He's a great **suppressor** of crime.

*Suppressant* on the other hand is more broad, and usually has to do with **physiology** or **pathology**. An example might be

> The new drug was found to reduce the incidence of the common cold by a factor of 5. Our product is shaping up to be a great disease **suppressant**.

So, in the case of *appetite*, **suppressant is the more accurate choice**. You might also note that the phrase *appetite-suppressant* is well-established simply as a common phrase, along with *disease-suppressant*.